# Unable to create a directory and save recorded file using Ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework

I am working on an Ionic 2 application. 
What it basically has to do is:

1. Record and Audio
2. Save that Audio file under Phone Memory's folder called "Diary"

This folder "Diary", I am to trying to create using Cordova File Plugin but with no success.

I am new to Ionic 2, and much newer to OOPS Concept too.

Here is my code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Media, MediaObject } from '@ionic-native/media';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';

@Component({
   selector: 'page-hello-ionic',
   templateUrl: 'hello-ionic.html',
   providers: [ Media, File]
})

export class HelloIonicPage {

visible:number = 1;

audio: MediaObject = this.media.create(this.file.dataDirectory+'recording.mp3');

constructor(private media: Media,private file: File) {

}

record() {

    if(this.visible==1) {
        this.visible = 0;
        this.audio.startRecord();   
    } else {
        this.visible = 1;
        this.audio.stopRecord();
        this.audio.release();
    }


  }
}
```

I am successfully able to record Audio in .3gp format but it gets saved to Device Memory with its Temporary names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out.

```
this.file.externalRootDirectory
```

This was the correct path, I wanted to use.

So, I changed my line from:

```
audio: MediaObject = this.media.create(this.file.dataDirectory+'recording.mp3');
```

To:

```
audio: MediaObject = this.media.create(this.file.externalRootDirectory+'recording.mp3');
```

And, everything worked as expected!